# Why won't enums deserialize with protobufs?

Tags: c#, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I have a class that I serialize, then deserialize using Protobuf-net version r431 (probably a year old or so).  The class contains an enum `_type` and a string called `_band`.  In the constructor, `_type` is set to StationType.Other and `_band` is set to an empty string.

As you can see I create an object with data, serialize, then deserialize.  The value of the enum `_type` (StationType.Streaming) is lost, while the `_band` (FM) is retained.

I feel this is an error, since the behavior is inconsistent.  However, if I start the enum from the value of 1 instead of 0, everything works as expected (e.g. all values are retained).

Am I missing something here?  See the code and the output below:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using ProtoBuf;

namespace ProtoBufsWithEnums
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            stn1 = new Station{Type = StationType.Streaming, Band = "FM"};

            var ms1 = new MemoryStream();
            Serializer.Serialize(ms1, stn1); // serialize
            byte[] bytes = ms1.ToArray();

            var ms2 = new MemoryStream(bytes);
            Station stn2 = Serializer.Deserialize<Station>(ms2); // deserialize

            Console.WriteLine("Type - Original {0}, New {1}", stn1.Type, stn2.Type);
            Console.WriteLine("Band - Original {0}, New {1}", stn1.Band, stn2.Band);
        }
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    public enum StationType
    {
        [ProtoEnum(Name = "Streaming", Value = 0)]
        Streaming = 0,
        [ProtoEnum(Name = "Terrestrial", Value = 1)]
        Terrestrial = 1,
        [ProtoEnum(Name = "Other", Value = 2)]
        Other = 2,
        [ProtoEnum(Name = "Group", Value = 3)]
        Group = 3
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    public class Station 
    {
        [ProtoMember(9)]
        private StationType _type;
        [ProtoMember(10)]
        private string _band;

        public Station()
        {
            _type = StationType.Other;
            _band = "";
        }

        public StationType Type
        {
            get { return _type; }
            set { _type = value; }
        }

        public string Band
        {
            get { return _band; }
            set { _band = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Type - Original Streaming, New Terrestrial
Type - Original FM, New FM
```

EDIT: Found [issue 251](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/issues/detail?id=251&q=enum&sort=-id) on the protobuf-net site, not sure if I am looking at the same issue or not.  Not quite sure whether it has been fixed or not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's the glitch:

```
public Station()
{
    _type = StationType.Other;
    _band = "";
}
```

protobuf-net makes some implicit assumptions about zero defaults. This works nicely in a lot of cases, but not all. The easiest way to help it here is to **tell it** that you are using a non-zero default:

```
[ProtoMember(9), DefaultValue(StationType.Other)]
private StationType _type;
```

Another option would be to tell it always to serialize it:

```
[ProtoMember(9, IsRequired = true)]
private StationType _type;
```

If you have *lots* of this, another option is to disable the "zero-default" behaviour, which can be done on a custom model:

```
var model = TypeModel.Create();
model.UseImplicitZeroDefaults = false;
```

then use `model.Serialize(...)` etc - but note that you should store and re-use a model like this (don't recreate it every time you need to serialize something), since that contains all the cached reflection/meta-programming output.

Answer (score 0):

Please mark the Enum with `[EnumMember]`

e.g.:

```
 [DataContract]
 [ProtoContract]
    public enum StationType
    {
        [EnumMember]
        [ProtoEnum(Name = "Streaming", Value = 0)]
        Streaming = 0,

        [EnumMember]
        [ProtoEnum(Name = "Terrestrial", Value = 1)]
        Terrestrial = 1,

        [EnumMember]
        [ProtoEnum(Name = "Other", Value = 2)]
        Other = 2,

        [EnumMember]
        [ProtoEnum(Name = "Group", Value = 3)]
        Group = 3
    }
```

Comment: It has no effect.  The problem persists.

Comment: @Angryum Hacker i forgot to mark the enum with [DataContract] please try now

Comment: Actually, you don't need to mark enums with anything for protobuf-net